# Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality question

Tags: cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Find the number of ordered quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ of nonnegative real numbers such that
\begin{align*}
a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 &= 4, \\
(a + b + c + d)(a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + d^3) &= 16.
\end{align*}

I have 21 as my answer since (1,1,1,1), (0,0,0,2), and $(0,0\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ and found all the combinations possible with (0,0,0,2) and $(0,0\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$,then adding up all the possible combinations and getting 21. However this answer is incorrect. What did I do wrong?

Comment: $(a, b,c,d)=(0,0,2,2)$ does not satisfy the second equation.

Comment: How is this a Cauchy-Schwarz inequality question?

Comment: He meant, that on can solve this system using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner How so?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde I meant (0,0,0,2). I'll fix it now

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner please do not assume my gender. That is rude.

Comment: Sorry for that!

Comment: I guess saying "He meant" is "the OP meant" for a genderless version. In German this is harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = 4$$

$$(a + b + c + d)(a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + d^3) = 16$$

By the C.S. inequality
$$(a + b + c + d)(a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + d^3) \ge (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)^2$$

In this case they are equal, and the equality holds only when:
$$\frac{a}{a^2} = \frac{b}{b^2} = \frac{c}{c^2} = \frac{d}{d^2}$$
$$\implies a = b = c = d = 1$$

Note that if any of $\{a,b,c,d\}$ are $0$, the ratios will not exist. We need to consider them on a case-by-case basis:

1. One of them, say $a=0$: In this case, $$b=c=d=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$$
2. Two of them are zero, say $a=b=0$. Then,
   $$b = c = \sqrt{2}$$
3. Three of them say $a=b=c=0$. Then $d=2$

Hence the solutions are:
$$\boxed{(a,b,c,d) = (1,1,1,1),\ (0, \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},\ \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}),\ (0, 0, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}),\ (0,0,0,2)}$$

Number of possibilities:

1. $(1,1,1,1) \implies ^4C_4 = 1$
2. $(0, \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}) \implies ^4C_1 = 4$
3. $(0, 0, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}) \implies ^4C_2 = 6$
4. $(0,0,0,2) \implies ^4C_1 = 4$

Hence the total number of cases seems to be $\boxed{15}$

Comment: That's not true, as you can see $(0,0,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ is a solution.

Comment: @kccu (-1, -1, -1, -1) is a solution as per this argument but the problem states that the numbers are non-negative. I need to check how CS works for zeros

Comment: If some of the terms are zero, then you need to apply C-S with fewer terms (e.g., $(a+b+c)(a^3+b^3+c^3)\geq (a^2+b^2+c^2)^2$ if $d=0$). You will find the additional solutions $(0,0,0,2)$, $(0,0,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$, and $(0, \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}})$, as well as all permutations of those.

Comment: @kccu I was just now writing down the exact same thing. Please take a look

Comment: Don't forget permutations of those (e.g., $(\sqrt{2},0,\sqrt{2},0)$, $(0,2,0,0)$, etc.).

Comment: I have added the possibilities. Was hoping to leave it to the OP but it's a small step